# Setting the up axis

Tags: opengl, coordinate-systems

What would be the easiest way to set what axis is the up axis?  Different data formats have different coordinate systems.  I need to, for example, load an object that is stored with the z axis as the up axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose one style and stick with it.  It really doesn't matter in the grand scheme of things.  If an object is in the wrong format then convert it to the right format ... job done.

Comment: Well, the thing is that the Collada file format has a tag called up_axis. I want to be able to support that tag without major code like converting to the right format. Being able to draw the same scene with different up axis. If the easiest way to do this is to crunch throught the data and output it with the correct up axis then maybe I won't support the tag yet.

Comment: If you've got a Collada file which defines an up-axis differently than you do in your scene, simply perform a change-of-basis on the Collada object to convert it into the desired world-space coordinate system.